# Android Python get gps status

Tags: android, python, gps, sl4a

New to Android Python scriptring comming from Symbian PyS60. I want to port my gps info PyS60 app to Android sl4a Python. I can get the location but that is about all. From API docs and Java examples it would seem that something like:
import android.location.LocationManager as lm
satus = lm.getGpsStatus()
would do the trick but I am getting nowhere.
Please help me on track (cython perhaps???)
Thanks, Janwillem

Answer (score 4):

a short example of python code using the GPS:

```
import android, string, time
droid = android.Android()
droid.startLocating()
time.sleep(10)
l = droid.readLocation()
```

I found this in the tutorial page of sl4a
http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/Tutorials
one of them is called: "Track where you go! Lua sample and python scripts to track your location."

the complete doc is in LocationFacade
Here: http://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/

Answer (score 1):

```
 import android, time
 droid = android.Android()
 droid.startLocating()
 time.sleep(15)
 loc = droid.readLocation().result
 if loc = {}:
   loc = getLastKnownLocation().result
 if loc != {}:
   try:
     n = loc['gps']
   except KeyError:
     n = loc['network'] 
   la = n['latitude'] 
   lo = n['longitude']
   address = droid.geocode(la, lo).result
 droid.stopLocating()
```

Comment: Here it is hope it helps! :)